# Как растянуть по всей высоте несколько элементов, не изменяя их размера?

Tags: android

У меня есть компоновка:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:background="@color/white"
              android:gravity="center_horizontal"
              android:padding="10dp">

        <ImageView android:id="@+id/logo"
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:background="@null"/>

        <TextView android:id="@+id/greeting"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/greeting"
                android:textSize="30sp"/>

            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button1"
                    android:text="@string/button1"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/button"
                    android:padding="10dp"/>
            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button2"
                    android:text="@string/button2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:background="@drawable/button2"
                    android:padding="10dp"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

Как можно растянуть эти четыре дочерних элемента на всю высоту экрана на равном расстоянии друг от друга, не изменяя при этом высоты самих элементов? Чтобы с увеличением высоты дисплея изменялась не высота элементов, а расстояние между ними? 
P.S. Может, мне стоит смотреть в сторону `android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"`?  Я пыталась использовать это свойство, но это мне не помогло, может, кто-то знает, как оно работает?

Хотелось бы получить что-то вроде этого:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

-Если вам надо сохранять позиционирование элементов относительно друг друга вам нужно использовать RalativeLayout

-Второй способ, в корневой лейаут положить ещё 4 лейаута, всем им задать равный layout_weight. Дальше в каждый из них положить по 1 элементу(Button, TextView и т.д...) и сделать gravity по центру лайаута в который вложен элемент.

Comment: Спасибо, это как раз то, что мне было нужно!

Answer (score 1):

Вставьте между ними пустые раздвигающие элементы `TextView` или `Space` (API level 14)

```
    <TextView  android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
```

Comment: Для этого есть "пустой" виджет [Space](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/widget/Space.html)

Comment: @pavlofff можно и так, только он с 4-го андроида появился